# Bind a click event to a dynamically created Dialog in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

[Original fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/48/)

[Failed example](http://jsfiddle.net/51h6tj9c/) for dynamically created dialog

I got this [script](http://blog.nemikor.com/tag/dialog-link/) to load AJAX content into a jQuery UI dialog whose class is named `.open_dia` in the fiddle examples. The problem is that I have the `.open_dia` dynamically loaded into the page in a `(window).bind(“load”, function(){} event` , so I want to know how to change this line from

```
var $link = $(this).one('click', function(){....
```

to something to the effect of

```
var $link = $('.area').one('click','.open_dia', function() {
```

so that I can bind the event to the dynamically created element `.open_dia` to open the dialog. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the original code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $loading = $('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Loading.gif" alt="loading" class="loading">');

    $('.open_dia').each(function() {
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .append($loading.clone());
        var $link = $(this).one('click', function() {
            $dialog
                .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
                .dialog({
                    title: $link.attr('title'),
                    width: 500,
                    height: 300
                });

            $link.click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog('open');

                return false;
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Failed Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').one('click',function(){
     $(this).next('.area').append('<a class="open_dia" title="this title" href="http://jsfiddle.net/">Click</a>');
});
    var $loading = $('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Loading.gif" alt="loading" class="loading">');
        $('.open_dia').each(function() {
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .append($loading.clone());
            var $link = $('.area').one('click','.open_dia', function() {
                $dialog
                    .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
                    .dialog({
                        title: $link.attr('title'),
                        width: 500,
                        height: 300
                    });
                $link.click(function() {
                    $dialog.dialog('open');

                    return false;
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
    });
```

Example HTML:

```
<button>Append open_dia</button>
<div class='area'></div>
```

Comment: Why did you attempt to use `.one()` rather than `.on()`?

Comment: @DevlshOne, the original uses `one` to make sure the AJAX content loads only once. I want to do that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I have forked your solution and made modification to your javasript as follows:

```
var loading = $('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Loading.gif" alt="loading" class="loading">');

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {     
            $(this).next('.area').append('<a class="open_dia" title="this title" href="#">Click</a>');        
        });

    $(document).on('click', '.open_dia', function (evt) {
        var dialog = $('<div></div>').append(loading.clone());

        dialog.load($(this).attr('href') + ' #content').dialog({
                title : $(this).attr('title'),
                width : 500,
                height : 300
        });

        dialog.dialog('open');
        return false;

    });       
});
```

My modified JS fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/91nc1k1t/2/

If you want to load each dialog's content only once, see this update of the forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/91nc1k1t/5/

Comment: Thank you. How can I use `one` with `on` to make sure that the Ajax Content loads on first click only? I have changed it from `on` to `one` but that doesn't work. The dialog only opens once. [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/91nc1k1t/4/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
<button>Append open_dia</button>
<div class='area'><a style="display: none;" class="open_dia"></a></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no problem if the target DOM `element` is dynamically generated. For it to work, please ensure that the event handler is registered on container element (parent of the dynamically created element)'s click event. This will fix the issue !