# Can't load AJAX content in jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I got this dynamically created JQueryUI dialog from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382590/bind-a-click-event-to-a-dynamically-created-dialog-in-jquery) that loads content via Ajax from `<a href='2.html'>`. But I found there is an issue with the following code. Even though AJAX request is successfully made as shown in Console, the content isn't able to append to the dialog container. Can anyone find out what's problem with the load function at this line:

```
dialog.load($(this).attr('href') + ' #content').dialog
```

I have tried

```
dialog.append($(this).data('source') + ' #content').dialog
dialog.text($(this).data('source') + ' #content').dialog
```

and they work.

Code:

```
var loading = $('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Loading.gif" alt="loading" class="loading">');

$(document).ready(function () {

   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('button').click(function () {
       $(this).next('.area').append('<a id="open_dia_'+Date.now().toString()+'"  class="open_dia" title="this title" href="2.html">Click</a>');
   });

    $(document).on('click', '.open_dia', function (evt) {
        var dialogid = 'dialog_'+$(this).attr('id');
        var dialog = null;
        if ($('#'+dialogid.toString()).length == 0)
        {
            dialog = $('<div id="'+dialogid+'"></div>').append(loading.clone());
            dialog.load($(this).attr('href') + ' #content').dialog({
                title: $(this).attr('title'),
                width: 500,
                height: 300
            });
        }
        else
        {
            dialog = $('#'+dialogid.toString());
        }


        dialog.dialog('open');
        return false;

    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that there is an space before your hash... Try this way:

```
dialog.load($(this).attr('href') + '#content').dialog({
  title: $(this).attr('title'),
  width: 500,
  height: 300
});
```

Comment: the space is likely on purpose, to load a specific element. Otherwise, it wouldn't make sense because hashes in ajax request urls don't do anything

Comment: @KevinB "2.html #content" IS invalid, "2.html#content" IS NOT.

Comment: Right, but when you use .load, `2.html #content` gets converted to `2.html`. http://api.jquery.com/load#loading-page-fragments

Comment: If this solved the problem... you can remove #content all together. removing the space in this specific case makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: The problem was fixed by removing the white space.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

Create a div, and a div inside that you'll use it to append the content.

```
<div id="dialogDiv" title="this title" style="display:none;">
  <div id='dialogDivDynamic'></div>
</div>
```

convert your first div in the dialog:

```
$("#selectionResult").dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: '900px',
        buttons: [{ text: "Close", click: functionToCloseDialog() }]
});
```

append the content to your second div:

```
$('#dialogDivDynamic').append("This is my new content");

function functionToCloseDialog() {
  $('#dialogDiv').dialog('close');
}
```